# How to expand a single sap.m.Tree item multiple levels?

Tags: sapui5

How to programmatically expand the only single node in sap.m.Tree control? JSONModel.

In example
http://embed.plnkr.co/jb9tggpFhv4DHg69785v/

Here I want to expand only node 1.2.1 without expanding all unneeded nodes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your sample add this line :

```
oTree.onItemExpanderPressed(oTree.getItems()[1], true)
```

after the oTree.place

This will expand the second item

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful for me. But I need to open node 1.2.1. I think, I can use onItemExpanderPressed and traverse through nodes. But is there more simpler method exists?

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote the given solution. `onItemExpanderPressed` is not a public API. Applications should rely only on what is visible in API reference. Also it doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

To expand one or more tree nodes programmatically, try the API [`sap.m.Tree#expand`:](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.Tree#methods/expand)

```js
var selectItemIndex = oTree.indexOfItem(mySelectedItem);
oTree.expand(selectItemIndex);
```

Sample: https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.Tree/sample/sap.m.sample.TreeExpandMulti

Comment: Welcome to SO! This unfortunately doesn't seem to answer the question